# Freemarker template to generate java code, and Reverse

Tags: templates, reverse-engineering, freemarker, pojo

I've started to learn some template engines for Java, and have choosen **Freemarker** as the starting one. Got the following question...

Having a template and a Pojo, generating an output, is it possible to generate the Pojo, having the output and the template through Freemarker?

If it's not, is there any other template engine that can do that?

Need any kind of **forward** (Pojo + Template = Output) and **reverse engineer** (Output + Template = Pojo)

[]s

Answer (score 0):

With freemaker, you can write template for code source java : you can write template for all text format.

You can write some java code, a pojo if you want, which generates a source java with this template and all stuff you want.

BUT with a Pojo, you can't generate this pojo itself.